# How to access properties of entities in EF Core dynamically?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a base `DatabaseContext` that inherits from `DbContext`. I'm trying to configure some properties of my entity models centrally.

Here's my code of `DatabbaseContext`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Company.DataAccess
{
    public abstract class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var allEntities = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().Select(p => modelBuilder.Entity(p.ClrType));

            foreach (var entity in allEntities)
            {
                // var properties = entity.GetProperties(); // this line throws exception
                // foreach (var property in properties)
                // {
                //  // if it's Guid, configure it this way
                //  // if it's Enum, configure it this way
                //  // if it's Date, configure it this way
                //  // ...
                // }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the line of `entity.GetProperties()` throws this error:

> DatabaseContext.cs: error CS1061: 'EntityTypeBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'GetProperties' and no accessible extension method 'GetProperties' accepting a first argument of type 'EntityTypeBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I get properties of my entity models?

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests `GetProperties` is not available on type `EntityTypeBuilder`. So you won't be able to call it. But `EntityTypeBuilder` as property `Metadata` on which you can call `GetProperties`. So try below -

```
entity.Metadata.GetProperties();
```